# Model.save and load giving different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model, save it, close the python session and in a new python session load the trained model and obtain the same accuracy. Currently when I try to do this, the loaded model gives random predictions and it is as though it wasn't trained.

The issue is not using the saved model in the same session. If I save a model from session 1 and load it in session 2 and use two exactly the same data to perform inference, the results are different.

Here is my save and load model.

Save Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=train_padded.shape[1]))

model.add(Conv1D(48, 5, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 50
batch_size = 32

history = model.fit(train_padded, training_labels, shuffle=True ,
                    epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=[ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0001),
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=2, verbose=1),
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', patience=5, verbose=1)])
model.save('model.h5')

scores = model.evaluate(train_padded, training_labels, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

```
84%
```

Load Model:

```
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

scores = model.evaluate(train_padded, training_labels, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

```
20%
```

To be more specific, the inference results from the session in which the model was built is much better compared to results from a different session using the same model.

The weights for both model are the same but their accuracy are drop as shown above

Comment: could you provide the code you tried to run? maybe you are doing something to the model in between the saving and loading.
Also, try to do the same by saving the weights only and load, see if the results are still different.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: You could try 2 things, loading it without compliling the model setting compile to false or save only the weights and and then compile the new model and setting the weights without avoiding to save the entire model

Comment: How much is the difference between the two accuracies or losses from the two models? Is it low or high?

Comment: @EladCohen i also try by saving the weights and load but still got the same result. which the result far away different

Comment: @jackve accuracy for load model is less than half of the training model.

Comment: @jackvei just update the code in my question.

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow can u provide the setting code for that?

Comment: @dan to load without compile you just need to set the compile flag to false in the load model method, to save only the weight you just need the 2 methods "save_weights" and "load_weights", you can find everything well documented on the keras site. https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/

Comment: i did both way. model.save (compile=false/true) and save_weights. i got different accuracy but same weights. is it because of the python version? @BestDogeStackoverflow